# How to determine the server url and port in the Global.asax Application_Start event

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

Is there any way to determine the url on which a website is being hosted from the Global.asax's Application_Start event?

I'm trying to store the url so that my application can generate dynamic links that are emailed from a background process.

If I try to directly access the HttpApplication.Request object in this method, I get a runtime error:

> System.Web.HttpException: Request is not available in this context

Comment: Why can't this be done in `Session_Start`?

Comment: The current HTTP context is not available at the time of Application_Start when running on IIS 7 or above in Integrated Mode.  As @Oded stated, Session_Start would work -- as would Application_BeginRequest, although Session_Start gets called a lot less frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting my code in the Global.asax's Application_BeginRequest event.

```
        string url = this.Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(this.Context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery, string.Empty) + this.Context.Request.ApplicationPath;
        if (url[url.Length-1] != '/')
        {
            url = url + '/';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get the url from the request with the following:

this.Context.Request.Url

From this you could determine the address including the port number for the application.

Comment: This worked on my local development machine (Cassini) but I get the error when I deploy to my server. Do you know if there is some IIS setting that may need to be set to have it work the same way?

Comment: System.Web.HttpException: Request is not available in this context